# Prism and Localization on the fly WPF

Tags: wpf, localization, prism

This my first question in this forum. Hopefully I will get a answer.
I am using Prism and MEF combination for my WPF based desktop application. Now I have implemented localization, such that on change on language from a combo box, the UI would reflect new language.

Problem is my region/views are already loaded & on change on language they are not refreshing.

Do I need to unload the region/views and reload them? Or there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look this: http://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html

Custom MarkupExtension for localization is a good general approach, but I don't know if it fits well to a Prims based project.

Comment: Just to cross check, this approach is applicable for RESX based localization? Because if we are using a locBAML based approach. Is this applicable for locbaml too?